# How to get markers one by one in google map api?

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps

I am Using google map API to show the markers for more than 50 locations but I am facing a problem of delay time it is taking to much time to load the markers on map.

Here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Google Maps</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>


    <div id="map" style="width:600px;height:400px;"></div>
    <div id="messages"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[


    // delay between geocode requests - at the time of writing, 100 miliseconds seems to work well
    var delay = 100;


      // ====== Create map objects ======
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

      // ====== Geocoding ======
      function getAddress(search, next) {
        geo.geocode({address:search}, function (results,status)
          { 
            // If that was successful
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              // Lets assume that the first marker is the one we want
              var p = results[0].geometry.location;
              var lat=p.lat();
              var lng=p.lng();
              // Output the data
                var msg = 'address="' + search + '" lat=' +lat+ ' lng=' +lng+ '(delay='+delay+'ms)<br>';
                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += msg;
              // Create a marker
              createMarker(search,lat,lng);
            }
            // ====== Decode the error status ======
            else {
              // === if we were sending the requests to fast, try this one again and increase the delay
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                nextAddress--;
                delay++;
              } else {
                var reason="Code "+status;
                var msg = 'address="' + search + '" error=' +reason+ '(delay='+delay+'ms)<br>';
                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += msg;
              }   
            }
            next();
          }
        );
      }

     // ======= Function to create a marker
     function createMarker(add,lat,lng) {
       var contentString = add;
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
         map: map,
         zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
       });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
         infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
         infowindow.open(map,marker);
       });

       bounds.extend(marker.position);

     }

      // ======= An array of locations that we want to Geocode ========
      var addresses = [
               '2780 Race Track Road Jacksonville, FL ,32259 USA',
'2770 Race Track Road Jacksonville, FL ,32259 usa',
'13700 Fario Road Jacksonville, FL ,32224 usa',
'10675-1 Atlantic Blvd Jacksonville, FL ,32225 usa',
'9052 New Kings Rd Jacksonville, FL ,32219 usa',
'12608 San Jose Blvd Jacksonville, FL ,32223 usa',
'5027-1 Sunbeam Rd Jacksonville, FL ,32257 usa',
'322 State Road 16 St Augustine, FL ,32084 usa',
'5850 Lenox Avenue Jacksonville, FL ,32205 usa',
'232 SR 16 St Augustine, FL ,32084 usa',
'1771 State Road 1-3 Jacksonville, FL ,32259 usa',
'1471 Monument Road Jacksonville, FL ,32225 usa',
'1625 Old Moultrie Road St Augustine, FL ,32084 usa',
'2825 Mayport Rd Atlantic Beach, FL ,32233 usa',
'10200 Beach Blvd Jacksonville, FL ,32246 usa',
'8041 N Main Street Jacksonville, FL ,32208 usa',
'500 State Road 13 Jacksonville, FL ,32259 usa',
'5748 Arlington Road Jacksonville, FL ,32211 usa',
'490 Levy Road Atlantic Beach, FL ,32233 usa',
'14476 Duval Place W Suite 204 Jacksonville, FL ,32218 usa',
'4671 Highway Avenue Jacksonville, FL ,32254 usa',
'4381 County Road 218 Middleburg, FL ,32068 usa',

      ];

      // ======= Global variable to remind us what to do next
      var nextAddress = 0;

      // ======= Function to call the next Geocode operation when the reply comes back

      function theNext() {
        if (nextAddress < addresses.length) {
          setTimeout('getAddress("'+addresses[nextAddress]+'",theNext)', delay);
          nextAddress++;
        } else {
          // We're done. Show map bounds
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
      }

      // ======= Call that function for the first time =======
      theNext();

    // This Javascript is based on code provided by the
    // Community Church Javascript Team
    // http://www.bisphamchurch.org.uk/   
    // http://econym.org.uk/gmap/

    //]]>
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

when i'm making this code dynamic with address it is taking to much time to load now i want to load the markers one by one.

Comment: If your addresses are fixed why don't you use the coords instead? I'm guessing what's causing the delay is the geocoding, not the markers

Comment: i'm getting address from the database..in above code i am just showing the logic which i'm using...

Comment: The question then becomes "why can't you save the coordinates in the database, along with the address"?

Comment: Actually i am new to it..will you please share the code or logic by which i can understand how to display markers with stored address and coordinates..??

Comment: which coordinates should i use? which is loaded from the google using api...or i should create the custom function to find coordinates?